# Extend custom Django/pinax app with own views/models

Tags: python, django, pinax

I am using Django with https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts application.
Which is actually an app named "account", and naturally, this app has its models/forms/views. As for now, I just call these views from urls.py.

What if I want to add views/models under "account" app name, how to go about it? Creating own account folder seems to lead to name conflict. On the other hand, editing django-user-accounts source to add own code looks like an overkill.

Comment: Why do you want to put them into the same app? Why not create a new app with a new name?

Comment: Only because all the code will deal with account in some way. It's just that 3rd party does the basic account management logic, and I would like to add a couple more specific views.

Answer (score 0):

Find the installed templates by pinax. These are generally in Lib\site-packages and copy all the templates to the app directory. Django will find your templates first and use them.